# FormGroup is deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder, formgroups

I've already seen some related question & answers, but unfortunately those didn't help me much.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(12)]],
      confirmPassword: [''],
    }, {validators: this.checkPasswords(this.form)});
  }
  checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
    let pass = group.controls.password.value;
    let confirmPass = group.controls.confirmPassword.value;
    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }
  }
  get newPassword() {
    return this.form.get("newPassword");
  }
  get confirmPassword() {
    return this.form.get("confirmPassword");
  }
```

I'm getting the error in **this.fb.group** this point. I want my custom validator work & also show error message in the view but I failed to do so.

Can anyone please tell what this error actually means & how to fix this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overload that you're using to create a `FormGroup` is deprecated.
Use another overload to achieve that, passing the form `validators` as `ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]` or just by passing the method `this.checkPasswords` without calling it `this.checkPasswords(this.form)` like the following:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group(
      {
        newPassword: [
          '',
          [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(6),
            Validators.maxLength(12),
          ],
        ],
        confirmPassword: [''],
      },
      { validators: this.checkPasswords }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you please create a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) with your code?

Comment: Sorry that I'm writing here again. I got several errors while writing in Stackblitz.

I cannot access the custom validator from my view, I've already tried many ways like

`<div *ngIf="form.hasError('notMatched') && confirmPassword.touched">
Doesn't match
</div>`

 `<div *ngIf="confirmPassword.errors.notMatched && confirmPassword.touched">
Doesn't match
</div>` etc

Can you please help me out?

Comment: I created a simple stackbiltz with your code, and it's working well. Please check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mrx7ea

Comment: Still remains deprecated-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm5mi.png

Comment: It still doesn't satisfy the desired objective. Please have a look at [WhoIsCarlo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182246/10082415). Consider changing it to retract my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I had the same issue and the answers here don't really provide a solution. So here's what I found:

Currently you have this **(group: FormGroup)**:

```
checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
    let pass = group.controls.password.value;
    let confirmPass = group.controls.confirmPassword.value;
    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }
  }
```

Change it to this **(group: AbstractControl)**:

```
checkPasswords(group: AbstractControl) {
    let pass = group.controls.password.value;
    let confirmPass = group.controls.confirmPassword.value;
    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }
  }
```

Everything will continue to work as is without the deprecated warning. Why is that the case and how does it make sense, no clue, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! That was getting on my nerves. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Amer is correct, the overload is deprecated... specifically the ability to pass the `options` argument of type `[key: string]: any`. Below is providing official Angular documentation on why.

> <strike>group(controlsConfig: { [key: string]: any; }, options: {
> [key: string]: any; }): FormGroup</strike>
>
> Deprecated This API is not typesafe and can result in issues with
> Closure Compiler renaming. Use the FormBuilder#group overload with
> AbstractControlOptions instead.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group

You must construct your options object in the shape of interface `AbstractControlOptions`

```
interface AbstractControlOptions {
  validators?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null
  asyncValidators?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null
  updateOn?: 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'
}
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlOptions#abstractcontroloptions